# Forgot path to module

Tags: python, module, python-3.9

I made a script called **sm on a linux-os**, which I want to update from python 3.6 to 3.9. But unfortunately I *forgo*t the path to this file. I tried it with the command *"locate sm.py"* but it showed me thousands of things, where the name was something like the file name "sm.py", and I don't want to read through it. So does anyone know how to find this file more precisely than my locate-command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in shell

```
find / -name "sm" -depth -exec echo {} \;
```

Comment: Tip, on most linux systems you can use `locate sm.py` to do a much faster search using an index that's updater daily. Also, `-exec echo {} \;` is not really needed; printing the results is find's default behavior.

Comment: But when you use locate, it lists all kind of stuff with the name sm.py in it.